# Protect Ubuntu system from MSFvenom attacks

Tags: networking, security

I have been reading about MSFvenom and its usage as a tool to attack devices connected to a common network (for example, see [here](https://www.offensive-security.com/metasploit-unleashed/msfvenom/) and [here](https://astr0baby.wordpress.com/2012/11/20/hacking-ubuntu-12-04-lts-using-metasploit/)). Kali is a well-known Linux distribution that implements MSFvenom.

Since realizing about this, I not longer connect my mobile device to free internet. Yet, since my computer uses Ubuntu, I imagine there must be a way to protect me from these attacks whilst connected to a free internet network. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MSFvenom is a component of the Metasploit Framework that is used to create payloads and is not something that is used to attack systems on it's own, it merely creates payloads.
 To keep your system "safer" from attackers, it's best to keep it fully updated, disable any services you don't use, uninstall any applications you don't use, install safe browser extensions (e.g. Chrome: netcraft, noscript, https everywhere, ghostery, ublock origin), keep flash and java uninstalled (unless absolutely required).
To provide additional security (for your computer and mobile device), use a VPN at all times and use DNS Encryption (e.g. DNSCrypt).